# Map Only Particular Fields from DTO -> Model Using Map-Struct

Tags: java, spring, datamapper, mapstruct

I have use case where i need to map or fill data for particular fields

for example : I Have a user Model which i need to convert to UserDTO with only
particular fields like username and accountId.

MODEL :

```
public class UserCore{

        private String accountId;

        private String username;
        private String workEmail;
        private String firstName;
        private String password;
        private String hashedPassword;

    }
```

UserDTO :

```
public class UserCoreDTO{

        private String accountId;

        private String username;
        private String workEmail;
        private String firstName;
        private String password;
        private String hashedPassword;

    }
```

is there any way in **map-struct** so that i can map only particular fields from source to destination

for example :

```
UserMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper( UserMapper.class );
mapper.map(fieldsToFetch,source,destination);
```

Comment: @DarrenForsythe i see in map-struct documentation i did n't find any support for above requirement that is why i came to SO. it is usual practice for every body to say what have you tried so far with out even understanding Question. not meant to hurt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example form the [docs](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#controlling-nested-bean-mappings):

```
@Mapper
public interface FishTankMapper {

    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(target = "fish.kind", source = "fish.type"),
        @Mapping(target = "fish.name", ignore = true),
        @Mapping(target = "ornament", source = "interior.ornament"),
        @Mapping(target = "material.materialType", source = "material"),
        @Mapping(target = "quality.report.organisation.name", source = "quality.report.organisationName")
    })
    FishTankDto map( FishTank source );
}
```

`ignore = true` will probably work for all fields, not just nested fields as in the example.

Comment: here we are hard coding field which needs to be excluded . my question is different.  is there any dynamic way can we do this? for example i'm developing an API which takes request param as fieldsToFetch=username,salary (i.e., API response should contain only username and salary). fieldsToFetch is client criteria.

Comment: What you are looking for can't work. Map struct generates java code for the mapping classes _at build time_. You will only know the fields at run-time you will have to look at tools that use reflection to solve this problem at runtime.  Be aware that the reason for mapstruct doing it at build time is not to incur the cost of reflection at runtime.